# Filtering a Firebase list by another Firebase Object in Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire

So i have a big firebase list that I want to filter using another firebase object that I am binding to. If I do not bind my 'search' object to firebase it filters just fine, but when i do bind to Firebase it returns zero results.

**my controller:**

```
  .controller('TestResultsCtrl', ['$scope', 'syncData', '$routeParams', '$firebase', '$filter', function($scope, syncData, $routeParams, $firebase, $filter) {
      $scope.id = $routeParams.id;
      syncData('tests/' + $routeParams.id).$bind($scope, 'test');
      syncData('tests/' + $routeParams.id + '/specs').$bind($scope, 'search');
      syncData('diagnoses').$bind($scope, 'all_diagnoses');
   }])
```

**my view:**

```
<a href="" ng-repeat="diagnoses in all_diagnoses | orderByPriority | filter:search" class="list-group-item">{{diagnoses.title}}</a>
```

a sample 'search' object:

```
{
  "constant": true,
  "intermittent": true,
  "localized": true,
  "referred": false,
  "region": "hip"
}
```

a sample of the 'diagnoses' firebase object/list:

```
{
  "constant": true,
  "intermittent": true,
  "localized": true,
  "referred": false,
  "region": "hip",
  "title": "Hip Osteoarthritis"
},
{
  "constant": true,
  "intermittent": false,
  "localized": false,
  "referred": true,
  "region": "neck",
  "title": "Whiplash"
}
```

**How do I get this to filter correctly?**
...and thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue probably is that the object returned from $bind contains several $ methods which Angular is trying to filter against.

Try something like this...

```
syncData('tests/' + $routeParams.id + '/specs').$bind($scope, 'searchDirty');
$scope.$watch('searchDirty', function (search) {
    $scope.search = angular.fromJson(angular.toJson(search));
});
```

This will strip out any $ methods/values and return the raw value of the data.